# Cant delete item from PagedDragDropGrid gridview android

Tags: android, gridview

I'm using the library [PagedDragDropGrid](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid) and I can not delete items. I call deleteItem(page,item) but no effect on the grid . I don't use the default behavior of draging item to delete area. I delete item by hand.

Have any one faced this problem ?